# Accessing another class property in Spritebuilder

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I am using spritebuilder with this organisation:

I have a GameScene.ccb file with top CCNode of class GameScene

I have a Board.ccb file with top CCNode of class Board

The Board ccb file is inserted into GameScene

I would like to add a sprite to my GameScene file (for visual purpose) but pointing to the Board class, property named target.

I can't manage to get this working with the Code connections tab. I tried every possibility, but the app crashes immediately with

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Board 0x7ba2b6b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key spriteFrame.'
```

I wonder if this is doable ?

Thank you.

Comment: Add your code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're coding in Objective-C, did you remember to import your header files? For example, in you GameScene.m, you would put at the top:

```
#import "Board.h"
```

This points to your Board class and whatever properties you have in that class when you create an instance of it via CCBReader:

```
 _boardName = (Board *)[CCBReader load:@"Board" owner:self];
```

Where _boardName is whatever you want to call your board, and you cast it as an instance of Board class, then load the ccb file named "Board."

This would work if you wanted to load it through code. Hope this helps.